# Factoring Trinomials: Dealing with Variables

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I'm current working with Trinomials, doing things such as $2w^2 + 38w + 140$. I know how to solve this, however, I encountered a different type of problem, where the last term has a variable in it: $x^3 - 10x^2 + 21x$. I'm not sure how to solve it when the $x$ is in that $21$.

Comment: I must presume you mean $x^3+10x^2+21x$ instead of $x^3=10x^2+21x$ as otherwise this is a problem about solving polynomials, not just factoring.

Answer (score 4):

The first step for any factoring problem is to factor out the greatest common factor, in this case $x$.

So $x^3 + 10x^2 + 21x$, we can factor out $x$ to get $x(x^2+10x+21)$. Can you then factor the remaining expression using the methods you already know?

Comment: Ah, I see now. This applies for all cases? So there is no other way to do it without factoring out that X, correct?

Comment: Factoring out the GCF is indeed the best way to do the factoring. It makes sense too -- if we want to write sums as products, and everything is multiplied by the same thing, the distributive property will help us write it as a product.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to factor trinomials, it's a good idea to see if you can find a common factor.  In this case, $x^3-10x^2+21x$, it's easy to see that there's a common factor, $x$.  Thus, you get $x(x^2-10x+21)$, and you can factor $x^2-10x+21$ using the tools for trinomials.

Comment: $x^2-10x-21$ does not factor nicely (over the integers). See my comment to OP's question.

Comment: Cats, it changed.